# Esper accepting http events - EsperIOHTTPAdapter

Tags: java, adapter, esper

I am very new to Esper and trying to get a small example to work.

I want to create a small java app that should accept events from an http stream. I noticed Esper has a HTTP adapter (`EsperIOHTTPAdapter`) out of the box. I am not sure how to use it though, I tried the following:

> ....initialize Esper and add listeners.....

```
        ConfigurationHTTPAdapter adapterConfig = new ConfigurationHTTPAdapter();
        // add additional configuration
        Request request = new Request();
        request.setStream("HeatSensorEvent");
        request.setUri("http://localhost:8077/root");
        adapterConfig.getRequests().add(request);

        // start adapter
        EsperIOHTTPAdapter httpAdapter = new EsperIOHTTPAdapter(adapterConfig, "sensorEngine");

        httpAdapter.start();
```

However, when I try this, the application stops immediately since the `start()` method does not wait. What is the best way to start an adapter to listen at a given port? I could do a `Thread.wait` inside an infinite loop, but I doubt that is the best way to go. Is it?

My alternative is to create my own webapp with Esper integrated and deploy it on a Tomcat instance, but I thought if there is an HTTP adapter in the product that I could make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat already provides its own HTTP server i.e. servlet engine. If the target is Tomcat you won't use the Esper HTTP adapter. Http servers are generally non-blocking. Thread.sleep can be used to make sure your program doesn't just exit.

Comment: The option to go for Tomcat is the alternative, if I can't get the HTTP Adapter to work. The Thread.sleep() option makes the application keep alive, but I don't see any process listening on port 8077 (based on netstat results and a "telnet open localhost 8077").